# I want to display location based information when overlay on map is clicked using android

Tags: android

I am designing the following application.

It shows several overlays on different places on map. I want some code that will show text information (location specific), when an overlay is clicked.

It's not just small text; a huge amount of data is associated with every overlay.

For example: To display hotel information about: Bangalore, Mumbai, Delhi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the popular [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) overlay. When an item is tapped a info bubble is displayed. Tapping on the bubble can also do other things.

Answer (score 0):

In your itemized overlay you can override the onTap event and display a dialog:

```
    @Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    MyOverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

This just displays the snippet and title from the overlay item, but you could add other logic to build and format the dialog message.

Edit:

If you have defined a constructor in your MyObject class that takes some key value,

and you have defined a proper

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) { }
```

in your MyObject class that will compare on that key value, and you have a either a

```
LinkedList<MyObject> myObjects;
```

or an

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;
```

you can do something like this:

```
int loc = myObjects.indexOf(new MyObject(keyValue));
if (loc != -1) {
myObject = myObjects.get(loc);
}
```

Comment: thanks.but am in search of "other logic" to display huge textual information.could u cprovide the code to do that.

Comment: It depends.  Is it in an array of objects?  Or in a database?  You could store a key value in the snippet field and then use that to find your information.

Comment: could u provide sample code,as how to incorporate array of objects.cos i am not intending to use a database